# How to make my local tomcat server accessible to www?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, firewall

So I have my "Hello World" Java project, using Intellij Idea, tomcat 7 is running. OS Windows 7. When I go to http://localhost:8080/ from my PC, it works fine. Now, I want the world to see my creation. I have static ip address 109.251.63.15. I believe I opened 80 port in firewall properly [image: firewall port exception props]
but I still get "page not found" when I go to 109.251.63.15. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to [configure port forwarding](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) on your router.

Comment: You have to configure port forwarding as @BackSlash says. Some routers though have a preloaded [DDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) configuration. Look at [some of the](https://www.dnsdynamic.org/) [famous](http://lifehacker.com/the-best-free-alternatives-to-dyndns-1561556205) [free Dynamic DNS](http://www.noip.com/).

Comment: can't you simply make your tomcat listen to port 80?

Comment: Yes guys, it was port forwarding issue. I plugged Internet cable directly into PC, and it worked. Harlandraka, thanks for link about port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

```
1-Download ngrok.
2-Run your service.
3-Assuming your tomcat server listen on port 8080, run ngrok in command line with this command:  ngrok.exe http 8080
```

Now, the client can run request with the url http://a9bb8562.ngrok.io/myapp.